# Highlight first result in Windows 7 search?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search

Is there any way to have the Windows 7 start search bar highlight the first result found so I can just hit Enter on the result rather than have to use the down arrow 2 times?

Currently, when I search for a file, it list all the matches and automatically highlights "See more results". I have to press the down arrow 3 times to highlight the first file match. This seems like a needless waste of keystrokes...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> jumps you to the Results Pane.

Edit:

As I commented before, for the Start Menu, your machine isn't the default behavior.  I'd try it on a fresh machine and look at the **shell extensions** you've installed.

Comment: Shift + F6 actually doesn't do anything for me in the start menu.

Comment: @AndyShinn: I read that wrong. I thought this was for Explorer. In the start menu, it automatically highlights the first result.

Comment: It does not on mine. No matter what I type in (even if there is only 1 result) the "See more results" link is highlighted first.

Comment: So I think I figured out what is happening. Search results for Programs are automatically highlighted. But Documents and Music are not. To get around this, I created shortcuts to common documents I use and pinned them to the Start Menu. This allows me to search them and hit enter on the first result. A silly workaround that only works on documents I specify. But if you would like to update your answer with this information I would be happy to accept it. I tried on another Windows 7 machine and it has the same behavior.

Comment: Edit: I also found another user with the same question which I did not find before: http://superuser.com/questions/70333/search-behavior-of-windows-7-start-menu